# set date to a specific timezone in html

Tags: javascript, html, datetime, calendar, timezone

I am using

```
<input id="123" type="date" name="date1">
```

I know this will use the default local time. Is there a way I could actually set it to a time with a specific time zone? 
For example, my local timezone is PST but I want this input to display a time in CST time. 
I have been looking for an answer for a while and still have no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use moment.js.
Use the below function after attaching moment.js to your html file.
pass **date** and **zone**.
you can get moment.js from https://momentjs.com/

```
function toTimeZone(time, zone) {
    var format = 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss ZZ';
    return moment(time, format).tz(zone).format(format);
}
```